# Reference book for XBee S3B radios

Tags: xbee

Is there a reference book/guide for advanced use of the XBee S3B radio modules from Digi?

(Yes, I already have the datasheet, but I want to know if there is another good reference for this.)

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Digi has a User Manual and a Development Kit Getting Started guide on the [S3B Documentation Page](http://www.digi.com/products/wireless-wired-embedded-solutions/zigbee-rf-modules/point-multipoint-rfmodules/xbee-pro-xsc#docs).

I would expect some of the content of Rob Faludi's [Building Wireless Sensor Networks](http://www.faludi.com/bwsn/) would apply to the S3B as well.

What interests you in the S3B modules as opposed to the more-common ZigBee-compatible 802.15.4 S2B modules?

Comment: I would expect a user of your experience to have read the [help/on-topic]: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Vote to close this sort of question rather than answering it. In addition, answers that consist almost entirely of links to off-site locations are not appropriate here.

Comment: Ok, I get it, I'm ok if you close the question.

Comment: @tomlogic my interest is in the long range of the modules.

Comment: @KenWhite, thanks for the reminder.  I've added a vote to close this question.